# Design a road from point A to point B subject to a minimum radius of curvature

Tags: python, optimization, vector, curve-fitting, smoothing

A road is recommended to pass through a number of (n) x,y,z points. I am trying to find the minimum smooth curve line to travel from point A to point Z while maintaining a minimum radius of curvature.

I am able to find the smooth line between the points but I cannot restrict the curvature to a certain radius of curvature.

For example in the below picture, the smooth line had gone through a short radius of curvature or a high degree of curvature which is physically not possible. How can I make the radius of curvature for this turn longer?

I am relatively new to programming, so I attempted the below code. The points represent point A and the points in between until point Z.

[image]

```
points=[[3.08066667,3.25593333,-1.49958947],[3.08066667,3.25669780,-1.49898697],[3.08066667,3.25746226,-1.44859092],[3.08066667,3.25822673,-1.39266809],[3.08066667,3.25899119,-1.35914138],[3.08066667,3.25975565,-1.26570602],[3.08066667,3.26052012,-1.09785688],[3.08066667,3.26128458,-1.15140859]]  


Smooth = np.array(points)

x, y = Smooth.T
i = np.arange(len(Smooth))


interp_i = np.linspace(0, i.max(), 100 * i.max())
xi = interp1d(i, x, kind='cubic')(interp_i)
yi = interp1d(i, y, kind='cubic')(interp_i)
ax.plot(xi, yi, color='black',linewidth=2)
```

The desired results is to get the minimum distance between the first point[0] to point[n] under different minimum radius of curvature. To get the minimum radius of curvature, a degree of curvature is specified (e.g. 40 degrees or 60 degrees) over a length (e.g. 1000 meters). The points in between point 0 and n can be adjusted to return the minimum smooth line.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Your example code is broken: `x, y = Smooth.T` doesn't work since `Smooth` has 3 columns.

Comment: Interesting optimisation problem. What algorithm are you using. It is not clear from the sample code. I'd expect some cost function to be minimized. I don't think this is a pure curve-fitting problem, but a global optimisation problem.